# Proof verification upper bound on the Mondrian Art Problem

Tags: solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds, open-problem, art

I have been doing some thinking on the [Mondrian Art Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49KvZrioFB0) and think I may have discovered something.

I think I have improved the upper bound for odd numbers from $k$ (for a $k$ by $k$ square) to $(5k+1) / 6$.  There may also be a better upper bound, but I haven't heard of one. My idea is to separate the odd numbers into three categories: $6n + 1$, $6n + 3$, $6n + 5$.  From there I create upper-bounds for each.  For the case of $(6n+1)$ I made this diagram:

[image: my 6n + 1 diagram]

You can see that all the sides add up to $6n+1 = k$.  The difference between the biggest and smallest is $5n+1$ (which is less than $k$).

I do the same thing for the other $2$ cases:

[image: my 6n + 3 diagram]

And...

[image: my 6n + 5 diagram]

The equations on the top right are the score (it should have a $k$ instead of $n$ there).

Thanks in advance for taking the time of reading /going through this.

PS: If it is correct where would I post it (or is **this** it?)

(EDIT: here is the [sequence](https://oeis.org/A276523).)